# How to order a list using the child dictionary inside using Linq?

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, dictionary

```
public class A {
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public Dictionary<string, decimal> B {get; set;}
}
```

How can I order a List< A > using values from B?
Example:

```
var list = new List<A>(){
  new A(){
    Name = "data1",
    B = new Dictionary<string, decimal>()
      {"QTY", 10},
      {"PRICE", 20}
  },
  new A(){
    Name = "data2",
    B = new Dictionary<string, decimal>()
      {"QTY", 100},
      {"PRICE", 200}
  },
};
```

**I want to order the list by "QTY" ascending.

Comment: Is that even possible or some convertion needs to be done first?

Comment: If you want only 1 entry in each instance of each Dictionary in `class A`, then you want a property of type `KeyValuePair<string, decimal>` instead of `Dictionary<string, decimal>`. If you intend to have more than one entry, nevermind my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the value and also make sure the Key is present in the dictionary

```
 var sortONPrice = list.OrderBy(x => x.B.ContainsKey("QTY") ? x.B["QTY"]:0);
```

If not then supply a value, I chose zero but it could be any arbitrary value.

Answer (score -1):

assuming you have a `var list = new List<A>()`, you want

```
var ordered = list.OrderBy(x => x.B.First(xx => xx.Key == "QTY").Value);
```

Which of course, does not include any null checks or checks against your dictionary to verify that the key `QTY` exists.  You'll want `FirstOrDefault` instead of `First` if you aren't sure if `QTY` exists on all items, and handle accordingly.

Comment: This answer is correct, but I don't like it because it's not utilizing the powers of the `Dictionary` class.